# Simplication using Algebraic modification

Tags: logic, boolean-expression, digital

Studying for exam and came thru this question:
Simplify using Algebraic modification put result in sum-of-product form with minimum # of literals

F(A,B,C,D)=(C'+AC'(BD+BD'))D+(BC'+(B+C)'+D')'+C(D+AB'(A'+D'))

I have expended it to this:

C'D+ABC'D+ABC'DD'+B'BD+B'CD+BCD+CD+AA'B'D+AB'CD

my final answer is: AD+AC+CD I'm trying to see if someone else have another thought on this.

Comment: I think you are in the wrong area for algebraic help.  Try one of the Maths sites.

Comment: Going through the transformations is a bit too time-consuming for me right now, but you can check your answer's correctness with a moderate effort by writing out the truth tables for both the original and your derivative to see if they match.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the answer after thoughtful calculation:

```
=(C'+AC'B)D+(BC'+B'C'+D')'+C(D+AB'D)
=C'D+ABC'D+(C'+D')'+C(D)
=C'D(1+AB)+CD+CD
=C'D+CD
= D
```